# How to change audio language track in VLC plugin in VB.Net?

Tags: audio, vlc

Some movies have multiple audio stream. How change audio language track in VLC plugin in VB.Net?

I Use this code to play the stream.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop()
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear()
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("http://192.168.1.60:8001/1:0:1:1778:18:6E:DCA0000:0:0:0:")
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By using this:

```
AxVLCPlugin21.audio.track = 2 ' or any track number
```